# Html Styling in textview goes wrong Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-styles, android-text-color

I am selecting a part of the TextView and on click of a "highlight" button, I am sending the start and the end index of selection to the database. Then I am loading all the start and end indexes from db and changing the color of text between them.

The problem is after once or twice, the app is changing the color of text that is not in selection.. and the selected part remains unchanged.

MY CODE:

1. When user selects and presses the highlight button

   ```
   int i=contentText.getSelectionStart();
   int j=contentText.getSelectionEnd();

   db.insertHiglightIndex(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(j));
   setHighlightedText();
   ```
2. The setHighlightedText() method..

   ```
   String fullText=contentText.getText().toString();
   for(int i=0; i<db.getAllStartIndex().size();i++){
       String a=fullText.substring(Integer.parseInt(db.getAllStartIndex().get(i)),Integer.parseInt(db.getAllEndIndex().get(i)));
       fullText = fullText.replace(a, "<font color='red'>"+a+"</font>");
   }
   contentText.setText(Html.fromHtml(fullText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
   ```

MY SCREENSHOTS.

**The selection:**

[image]

**The Result:**

[image]

Clearly the selected area is from **"Garrick"** to **"Bart"**, and the result is from **"entity"** to **"2012"**

I am not able to understand why is this happening. I think there is some problem with this `<font color='red'>"+a+"</font>` line.

Thank you

Comment: You want selection to be colored red, But wrong text got colored. Is it what you are trying to explain ? & *The problem is after once or twice* means, First or second time it works properly but third time it doesn't work is it ? If it doesn't work then what actually happened at third or fourth try ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna First or second time it works properly but third time it doesn't work . In the subsequent tries, some text from previous indexes gets selected, not the indexes that I selected

Comment: Found out your issue, And added an answer as well, If any query you got, you can freely ask. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got wrong indexed because There is already added `<font color='red'>` in the beginning, So that in second time This tag is also counted as a part of string, So I suggest creating a new temporary String, assign same text to the String but after replacing the previous font tag it held. Use this syntax to remove previous `font` tag from `originalString`

```
String tempString = originalString.replaceAll("[<](/)?font[^>]*[>]", "");
```

After that work with only `tempString`. That means again add every previous `font` tag you have to `tempString` and set that text.

In next time again do the same first remove all font tag and again add all of them back in `tempString` as well as current selection using same loop you are using currently.

Comment: Hey it is working fine.. but I didn't understand what happened. If I repleced all the <>/ tags, then how does the Html.toHtml() work?

Comment: Simple that replaces all the `font` tag it was holding with empty string, That means it removes them. Then you will get the fresh String without that tag and then your substring will point to the correct index of string, Did you get it ?

Comment: got it :).. thanx a lot

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong indexes because you are modifying the `fullText` content within the loop.

Taking a look at this example you can figure it:

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setText( "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");

String fullText= tv.getText().toString();

// your first iteration
String a = fullText.substring(1,3);
// a contains "ab"
fullText = fullText.replace(a, "<font color='red'>"+a+"</font>");
```

After the first iteration full text contains now

```
a<font color='red'>bc</font>defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
```

Then the `substring()` in the second iteration won't returns the substring base on your initial content.

If you want to be able to have multiple substrings colored in red you can try this:

```
String fullText = contentText.getText().toString();
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0; i < db.getAllStartIndex().size(); i++){
    fullText = applyFont(result, fullText, Integer.parseInt(db.getAllStartIndex().get(i)), Integer.parseInt(db.getAllEndIndex().get(i)));
}
// Add here the remaining content
result.append(fullText);
contentText.setText(Html.fromHtml(result.toString()), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);


private String applyFont(StringBuilder result, String source, int from, int to){
    result.append(source.substring(0, from));
    result.append("<font color='red'>");
    result.append(source.substring(from, to));
    result.append("</font>");
    return source.substring(to, source.length());
}
```

Comment: Okay.. so can you tell how can I achieve what I am trying to do? In the for loop, I am using the list from the database which contains all the start and end indexes